# Is there any way to ensure all CheckpointListeners notified about checkpoint completion on Flink on job cancel with savepoint?

Tags: java, apache-flink, flink-streaming, checkpointing

I'm using flink 1.9 and the REST API `/jobs/:jobid/savepoints` to trigger the savepoint and cancel job (stop the job gracefully to run later on from savepoint).

I use a two-phase commit in source function so my source implements both `CheckpointedFunction` and `CheckpointListener` interfaces. On `snapshotState()` method call I snapshot the internal state and on `notifyCheckpointComplete()` I checkpoint state to 3rd party system.

From what I can see from source code, only the `snapshotState()` part is synchronous in `CheckpointCoordinator` -

```java
// send the messages to the tasks that trigger their checkpoint
                for (Execution execution: executions) {
                    if (props.isSynchronous()) {
                        execution.triggerSynchronousSavepoint(checkpointID, timestamp, checkpointOptions, advanceToEndOfTime);
                    } else {
                        execution.triggerCheckpoint(checkpointID, timestamp, checkpointOptions);
                    }
                }
```

The checkpoint acknowledge and completion notification is asynchronous in `AsyncCheckpointRunnable`.

That being said, when the `savepoint` with `cancel-job` set to `true` is triggered, after the snapshot is taken, some of the Task Managers keep up to receive completion notification before the job cancelling and execute `notifyCheckpointComplete()`, and some not.

The question is whether there is a way to cancel job with savepoint so that the `notifyCheckpointComplete()` is guaranteed to be invoked by all Task Managers before job cancelled or there is no way to achieve this at the moment ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wouldn't using stop-with-savepoint[1][2] solve the problem?

[1]https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/monitoring/rest_api.html#jobs-jobid-stop
[2]https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/ops/cli.html

Comment: According to my observations, notify checkpoint completed gets invoked asynchronously and not all task manager receive this notification before been canceled.

Comment: I would expect that all tasks that implement the CheckpointListener interface receive the notification about a checkpoint being completed in the case of stop-wiith-savepoint. This is what guarantees that all sinks will also commit to the external systems used as sinks. Have you observed a specific type of task that does not?

Comment: yes, I did. In source function `notifyCheckpointComplete` is not sometimes invoked.

Comment: Thank you, Kostas! You are right! I was using the different endpoint - savepoint-with-cancel, which I thought is similar to the stop-with-savepoint. However, digging into the code turns out that the stop-with-savepoint is synchronous, meanwhile savepoint-with-cancel - asynchronous. So, switching to stop-with-savepoint solved the problem.

Comment: Great to hear that!

Answer (score 2):

It's been a while since I looked at Flink 1.9 so please take my answer with some caution.

My guess is that your sources cancel too early. So `notifyCheckpointComplete` is actually sent to all tasks, but some `SourceFunction`s already quit the `run` and the respective task is cleaned up.

Afaik, what you described should be possible if you ignore cancellation and interruptions until you have received the last `notifyCheckpointComplete`.

```
class YourSource implements SourceFunction<Object>, CheckpointListener, CheckpointedFunction {
    private volatile boolean canceled = false;
    private volatile boolean pendingCheckpoint = false;

    @Override
    public void snapshotState(FunctionSnapshotContext context) throws Exception {
        pendingCheckpoint = true;
        // start two-phase commit
    }

    @Override
    public void initializeState(FunctionInitializationContext context) throws Exception {

    }

    @Override
    public void notifyCheckpointComplete(long checkpointId) throws Exception {
        // finish two-phase commit
        pendingCheckpoint = false;
    }

    @Override
    public void run(SourceContext<Object> ctx) throws Exception {
        while (!canceled) {
            // do normal source stuff
        }
        // keep the task running after cancellation
        while (pendingCheckpoint) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // ignore interruptions until two-phase commit is done
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void cancel() {
        canceled = true;
    }
}
```